# Finder Sync Extension no badges on desktop

Tags: macos, finder, badge, findersync

i have Finder Sync Extension which is showing badges on folder and files.
But there is one issue - it does not shows badges for folders on my Desktop. Meanwhile i can see it in Finder. (check the screenshot please)

A there any way to show it?

[image: Screenshot]