# How to display badge icon on Desktop using Finder Sync Extension?

Tags: macos, findersync

I wrote a Finder Sync Extension to display a badge icon on file.

It works fine with folder that open in finder, but the badge icon can not been seen on desktop.

After check the log output, it seem that `beginObservingDirectoryAtURL:` is not called when plugin running.

[image: can't see badge on desktop]

Comment: Also asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47055472/finder-sync-extension-no-badges-on-desktop